# How to make HTTP calls inside a loop and wait for one to finish before making another?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, ngrx

I have an array of items which on each element I want to make an HTTP call, wait for it to finish, then make another call, only one at a time.

I tried:

```
index(item) {
   return this.service.index(item).pipe(
      map(response => {
         // handle success case
      }),
      catchError(error => {
         // handle error case
      })
   )
}

async processArray(array) {
  const promises = array.map(item => this.index(item));
  await Promise.all(promises);
}

proccessArray(array);
```

Also with NGRX Effects:

```
@Effect()
effect$ = this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType<action>(actionTypes.action),
   mergeMapTo(this.store.select(getMyArray)),
   flatMap((request: any[]) => {
       return zip(...request.map(item => {  
         return this.service.index(item).pipe(
               map(response => {
                  // handle success case
               }),
               catchError(error => {
                  // handle error case
               })
            )
         }))
      }),
   );
```

Also tried doing it in `for` and `forEach` loops but they fire all the requests at once. How could I achieve this?

Comment: You can use recursive function here which will call itself after getting response for previous array item

Comment: Where are the HTTP calls you want make? In `request`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using promises and want to wait for each promise to resolve before another call is made then (1) you should not use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as this will wait til all requests are resolved and (2) you need to use a plain old for-loop which enables you to wait for async operations within the loop.

```
async processArray(array) {
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    await yourServiceCall();
  }
}
```

As a sidenote: Since you are using async-await, don't forget to [convert](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html) your observables to promises.

If you want to move away from promises (and async-await) and rely on pure RxJS instead, have a look at [concatMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap):

> Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable, in a serialized fashion waiting for each one to complete before merging the next.

For example:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';

ngOnInit() {
  from(myArray)
    .pipe(concatMap(el => yourServiceCall(el)))
    .subscribe(/* your logic */);
}
```

Comment: `concatMap` operator solved the problem. It only subscribes to the next observable if the previous one has finished. Thanks!